# Prefixed and non prefix commands are not working together on python discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import chalk


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Test'))
    print("All systems online and working " + bot.user.name)
    await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id=386518608550952965), "All systems online and working")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hel(ctx):
    await bot.say("A help message is sent to user")


@bot.command
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("ping"):
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "Pong")




bot.run("TOKEN", bot=True)
```

I'm trying to get this work on my discord test server but when I use it like this, only the first "on_ready" and !hel command works, ping doesn't print anything, but when I delete the !hel commands code part, ping works, is there any way that I can make them work together?

Comment: In `hel`, is `sot.say` supposed to be `bot.say`?

Comment: Ah, yes, I just didn't realised it, I changed the regular name into "bot" here to make it look simpler and mistyped it. It's correct in my original code

Answer (score 2):

Change `@bot.command` to `@bot.event` when using `on_message`

Add `bot.process_commands` when using `on_message`

> **Why does on_message make my commands stop working?**
>
> Overriding the default provided on_message forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a bot.process_commands(message) line at the end of your on_message. For example:
>
> ```
> @bot.event
> async def on_message(message):
>     # do some extra stuff here
>
>     await bot.process_commands(message)
> ```

http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Your code should look like this:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import chalk


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Test'))
    print("All systems online and working " + bot.user.name)
    await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id=386518608550952965), "All systems online and working")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hel(ctx):
    await bot.say("A help message is sent to user")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("ping"):
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "Pong")

    await bot.process_commands(message)


bot.run("TOKEN", bot=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `@bot.command` above `on_message` with `@bot.event`