# Python Bot command not working but event is

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Commands not working but events are tried overriding my `on_message` but that didn't work. When I comment out the second `client.event` and down `client.command` works. Any idea of what I could be doing wrong? am I missing something?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import time 
from datetime import date

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

#client = discord.Client()



@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.command()
async def clr(ctx, amount=5):
   await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)



@client.command(aliases =['should', 'will'])
async def _8ball(ctx):
    responses =['As i see it, yes.',
                'Ask again later.',
                'Better not tell you now.',
                "Don't count on it",
                'Yes!']
    await ctx.send(random.choice(responses))


 @client.event()
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
     return
    
    

  if message.content.startswith('hello'):
     await message.channel.send('Hello how are you?')
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py @bot.command() not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207823/discord-py-bot-command-not-running)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) (the ones mentioned by moinierer3000 in the comments) as well as other questions on stack (listed below), `on_message` will stop your commands from working if you do not process the commands.

```py
@client.event()
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
     return
  if message.content.startswith('hello'):
     await message.channel.send('Hello how are you?')
  await client.process_commands(message)
```

**Other questions like this**:

- [discord.py @bot.command() not running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208333/14420546)
- [Discord.py Commands not working because of a on_message event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64608513/14420546)
- [Prefixed and non prefix commands are not working together on python discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751873/14420546)